# How Can I implement User Sent Message and Receive Message in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project where I have three types of users: Landlord, Agent, and Prospect. I want the Prospect user to be able to contact the Property Owner by sending a message while on the Property Detail view, and the Property Owner to be able to reply back to the Prospect using the same view. I also want all these users to maintain an Inbox and Sent Message items. I'm struggling to figure out whether my logic is sound and how to implement the functionality using Django. Is there a library that will make user messaging within Django easier?

In my code, I maintain different Models for these users with a OneToOneField and use signals for automatic profile creation upon registration. I also have a Profile Model connected through the same relationship, and Message Model. I tried passing the Property Owner ID as the Recipient ID and Property ID on url from the Property Detail view to the send_message function view, but I get the error "No 'User matches the given query'."

Here are my views:

```py
def property_detail(request, property_id):
    user = request.user
    #Check if user is authenticated 
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        logout(request)
        messages.warning(request, 'Session expired. Please log in again.')
        return redirect('account-login')  # Replace 'login' with your actual login URL
    
    property_instance = get_object_or_404(Property, pk=property_id)

    properties = []  # Initialize 'properties' as an empty list

    property_owner = None

    # Get the properties for the current user
    if hasattr(user, 'landlord'):
        properties = Property.objects.filter(landlord__user=request.user).prefetch_related('agent').order_by('-last_updated')[:4]
        
    elif hasattr(user, 'agent'):
        properties = Property.objects.filter(agent__user=request.user).prefetch_related('landlord').order_by('-last_updated')[:4]
    
    #Get prospect user profile   
    elif hasattr(user, 'prospect_profile'):
        properties = Property.objects.order_by('-last_updated')[:4]
        if property_instance.landlord:
            property_owner = property_instance.landlord
        elif property_instance.agent:
            property_owner = property_instance.agent
            
       
    context = {
        
        'properties':properties,
        'property_owner': property_owner,
        'page_title': 'Property Detail',
        'property': property_instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'realestate/property_detail.html', context)

def send_message(request, property_id, recipient_id):
    property = get_object_or_404(Property, id=property_id)
    recipient = get_object_or_404(User, id=recipient_id)

    try:
        recipient = User.objects.get(id=recipient_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # Handle the case when the recipient doesn't exist
        message.warning(request, 'Recipient Does Not Exist.')
        return redirect('account-login')  # Or re
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.cleaned_data['content']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            
            message = Message(sender=request.user, recipient=recipient, subject=subject, content=message, property=property)
            message.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Message sent successfully.')
            return redirect('inbox')
        
    else:
        form = MessageForm()
       
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'page_title': 'Send Message',
        'recipient': recipient,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'realestate/send_message.html', context)
```

Here is the Message model:

```py
class Message(models.Model):
    SUBJECT_CHOICES = [
        ('Inquiry', 'Inquiry'),
        ('Reinquiry', 'Reinquiry'),
        ('Negotiation', 'Negotiation'),
        ('Payment', 'Payment'),
    ]

    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sent_messages')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='received_messages')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.sender.username} - {self.recipient.username}'
    
    def mark_as_read(self):
        self.status = True
        self.save()
```

Comment: Can you share a unit test that reproduces the problem?